# HTTPS/ SSL RSS integration with Feedburner 404 Error

Tags: javascript, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

Since I have upgraded my website to https (ssl) due to recent change of GOOGLE Search Updates. But it was not easy for me. The google too is not using `HTTPS` in Feedburner Syndication service.

I have used Yahoo Pipes to deliever my `HTTPS` contents and then I used Yahoo Output Pipe as the `Feedburner RSS Link` and it is working fine.

But I need some other way Like `(.htaccess)` mod-rewrite or other way to directly communicate with feedburner.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for the same. Found two solutions
One is by using subdomain with php command file_get_contents(); must be enabled on your host.

Complete tutorial
https://www.webhostinghero.com/https-source-urls-google-feedburner/

And another with .htaccess

https://pabst-socialmedia.com/fixing-feedburner-rss-feed-problem-https-wordpress-websites/

Hopefully these will solve your problem.